# Jquery Dom Selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dom

I have one empty span span id="ajax_responce"

I am pusing html (div and ul, li) using ajax like this

```
<div class="row" id="taskbar"><div class="col-md-3">
    <div  class="column left first">
        <ul class="sortable-list ui-sortable col_backlog">
            <li id="123" class="sortable-item" style="">
            .......
            .......
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
 ......
```

Problem :: 1. I am trying to apply jquery ui method sortable like this

```
            $('#taskbar .sortable-list').sortable({
                connectWith: '#taskbar .sortable-list',
                placeholder: 'placeholder',
            });
```

sortable method not working, there is any issue in dom selector

Thanks
V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recall the sortable plugin for dynamically added element. Reinitialize the sortable function inside your ajax success callback after you dynamically generated element is appended to a DOM

```
$.ajax({
   ....
  //your stuff
  success :function(){  //if you are using latest jQuery version, this should be .done callback
     .... //code to append your div and ul, li (you should already have this)
     $('#taskbar .sortable-list').sortable({
            connectWith: '#taskbar .sortable-list',
            placeholder: 'placeholder',
        });
  };
```

Comment: welcome.. you should start accepting answer if it helped you.. do the same for some of your other question..http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work